# Конвертер валют на Java/swing . Как подгружать курс из онлайна?

Tags: java, swing, конвертер

Всем привет. Хочу написать простую программу из Топика.
Интересует, если кто-то делал уже, последовательность действий и что нужно использовать. Насколько я знаю, мне нужно написать не посредственно UI на swing/java и потом уже запросами(как??, на каком языке?) через API подгружать в десктопное приложение. Если есть пример, сбросьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно загрузить json с сайта Центробанка и извлечь нужные данные. https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js

Answer (score 1):

я бы на твоем месте сделал пару классов, которые подтягивают данные из какого-то сайта (вообще любого) с помощью парсинга html (библиотека json хорошая в этом плане).

куча видосов в интернете по запросу "парсинг html json java". далее эти классы буду передавать инфу на твой ui.

если есть вопросы - спрашивай

Comment: Сделал парсинг. Получился результат на картинке, вышло много не нужной информации. Подскажи, пожалуйста, как из результата извлечь валюту? Более точную выборку атрибутов или делать поиск внутри текста методами Java.

Как я себе представляю: Нужно оставить строку с валютой и строку с значением. Значение я конвертирую в double и вывожу в UI. Так?

Comment: Нужно посмотреть на разметке html сайта где находится именно то, что нужно тебе и извлекать только это. Очевидно же